# addEventListener for the same event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

So I have a few div tags that I have currently hidden, and I want to display them one after the other by hitting the enter key.

What I want to happen: I hit enter and the first div tag is revealed, and then I hit enter a second time to see the second div tag.

What is happening instead: I hit enter once and both div tags show up.

In this case, the first div tag I want to reveal is "intro", and the second is "body". I am running this website on jsbin, and I am using chrome, if that helps.

This is my JavaScript:

```
//***********************************************************

//  BODY MODULE

var bodyController = (function(){
  var enterBool;

  var reveal = function(){
    if(enterBool){
      document.getElementById("evidence").style.display = "block";
      enterBool = false;
    }
  };

  var enterListen = function(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 13){
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
          if(event.keyCode === 13){
            enterBool = true;
            reveal();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  return{
    enterBoolBody: enterBool,
    enterListenBody: function(){
      enterListen();
    }
  }
})();

//***********************************************************

//  INTRO MODULE

var introController = (function(){
  var enterBool;

  var reveal = function(){
    if(enterBool){
      document.getElementById("body").style.display = "block";
      enterBool = false;
    }
  };

  var enterListen = function(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 13){
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
          if(event.keyCode === 13){
            enterBool = true;
            reveal();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  return{
    enterBoolIntro: enterBool,
    enterListenIntro: function(){
      enterListen();
    }
  }
})();

 //***********************************************************

 //  CONTROL MODULE

 var controller = (function(introCtrl, bodyCtrl, evidenceCtrl, infoCtrl, 
 conclusionCtrl){  
  var eventListeners = function(){
     introCtrl.enterListenIntro();
     bodyCtrl.enterListenBody();
  };

  return{
    init: function(){
      eventListeners();
    }
  }
 })(introController, bodyController, evidenceController, 
    infoController, conclusionController);

 //***********************************************************

 controller.init();
```

Comment: why are you binding events inside of events?

Comment: Are you referring to: 
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 13){
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
          if(event.keyCode === 13){
            enterBool = true;
            reveal();
          }
        });
      }
    });

If so, I was writing it that way because I thought it would make sure that the key had gone back up before checking if the key was going to go down again.

Comment: I am pretty new to JS, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **make sure that the key had gone back up**: keyup event only fire when that key is **up** so i think you just need to add keyup EventListener

Comment: I do have a keyup eventListener :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the ids of your divs in an array, or you could assign a common class to all divs that you want to appear one by one.  Assuming the first, this code simply grabs the id of the next div to display from the array and increments the counter.  You could add more divs to the array and it would work.

```
var divs = ["evidence", "body"];
var counter = 0;
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
  if(counter < divs.length && event.keyCode == 13){
    document.getElementById(divs[counter]).style.display = 'block';
    counter++;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works seamlessly, and now I can add as many divs as I want.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be over engineering this a bit.  All you need is an event listener to check for enter.  Then you check if the first div is shown, if not show it.  If the first div is shown check if the second div is shown and show it.

Quick note, no IE9 support for classList if that's important to you.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

```js
(function(window, document, undefined)
{
  document.addEventListener('keyup', showDivs, false);
})(window, window.document);

function showDivs(event)
{
  event = event || window.event;
  var divsToShow = document.getElementsByClassName("Display-Div");

  for (var i = 0; i < divsToShow.length; i++) {
    if (!divsToShow[i].classList.contains("Block")) {
      divsToShow[i].classList.add("Block");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.Hidden {
  display: none;
}

.Block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">This</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">Now</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">Works</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">With</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">Any</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">Div</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">With</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">Class</div>
<div class="Hidden Display-Div">Display-Div</div>
```

Comment: I think I tried your approach properly, but it did not work. I think I may not have support for classList. I am also not sure how to check this.

I also want to continue this process with at least 2 more div tags, and I think your approach may not be optimal for 2+ div tags. Unless you think I really should use a bunch of if elses, or maybe switch statements.

Comment: Any modern browser should support classList.  If you want to add more divs you would you a solution like James' and either put them in an array or add a specific class to them.  I'll update the answer with multiple div support.